# Nservicebus and sqlite

Tags: .net, sqlite, nservicebus, asp.net-4.8

i am trying to have an existing application running on .net 4.8 using nservicebus access a sqlite database.
Problem is: the projec is library type and on debug it starts nservicebus.host.exe to run.
Sqlite creates both x64 and x86 folders when debugging .
Nservice at configuration tries to load everything,including x64 one and throwing exception.
Is there anyway to stop this kind of logging or at least have sqlite not create both folders?
Thank you

Tried both sqlite3 nuget package and system.data.sqlite to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but...

1. Don't use [NServiceBus Host](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/). Since version 8, it's no longer supported.
2. [Here's more information](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/) on how to host your NServiceBus endpoints
3. There's an entire workshop running on NServiceBus that makes use of SqlLite for store that you can find here: https://github.com/Particular/workshop/
4. If you encounter more issues with hosting or anything else, contact Particular Software at support@particular.net for help. There's even [free help with a proof-of-concept](https://particular.net/proof-of-concept).

Comment: Oh i wish.I swear i wish i could but I have to use preexisting architetture so my hands are tied there

Comment: can't change preexisting architecture, but introducing SqlLite?! :-)
Sounds a bit off? Anyway, execute step #4 in my reply :-)